# Trying to remember a Fantasy book/short story I read about powerful maybe enslaved humans with 6 fingers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Ok so I'm desperately trying to find the author/title of a fantasy book or perhaps a short story I read maybe a decade ago.

It focused on a female character who was "other" compared to normal people but she wasn't that rare- they were like a higher evolved human/somewhat magical perhaps. They seemed to be mainly noble/wealthy/of higher birth.

Their major feature that defined them from others was a 6th finger on each hand; the females had them amputated very early in life, and they were not allowed to partner/mate with males of the same ilk. They were encouraged to have other female companions - can't remember if they were allowed to marry non "other" makes.

The story focused on this one female who had not had her 6th fingers removed. She meets a male of her kind who she has a very strong reaction too; they exchange blood which activates immense power in them both. Turns out the females are the most powerful and especially when stimulated by blood exchange/sexual contact with a male?

I can't seem to remember anything else and I can't for the life of me find it anywhere!!

Anyone have any ideas???

Comment: Hmm. [Does this sound familiar?](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1ibmba/tomt_old_book_fantasy_book_blonde_magicuser_with/)

Comment: @Valorum I am too lazy for that.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103358/looking-for-name-of-a-book-series-spaceship-crashed-civilization-based-on-mag

Answer (score 5):

Could this be (one of) the [Darkover](https://www.goodreads.com/series/50144-darkover) novels by Marion Zimmer Bradley?

A key race featured in the books are the *Chieri* who (normally) have six fingers.

> *Chieri are a non-human race native to Darkover. At time of Darkover
> Landfall they are a dying race, that traveled the stars and settled
> back to Darkover.*
>
> *They are tall and willowy, with pale skin, silvery grey or golden eyes
> and long silky golden or white hair.  **They possess six fingers on
> their hands and are humanoid enough to reproduce with humans.**  They
> usually appear androgynous or sexless but are actually hermaphrodites,
> they change orientation depending on the need.  When in their natural
> state it is known as emmasca, usually when they find a mate one must
> be male or female and this will cause a shifting of the other to be
> the opposite so mating and procreation can occur.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Darkover Wiki: Chieri](http://darkover.wikia.com/wiki/Chieri)</sup></sub>

Comment: Just saw this.  I don't think so.  Some of the Comyn (I think especially Aillard) have six fingers, and they are human, not chieri.  But they do not have them removed; it is just accepted.  But both men and women had six fingers.  And people with six fingers married like anyone else.  And nothing about the blood exchange activating power.