# Trying to remember the name of a book I read in the 90s

Tags: story-identification, novel

So this is going to be the worst description in the history of any book description ever, but when I was a young teenager I read a sci fi book that I haven't been able to remember the name or author of since.  It has been like 15 years and I was a kid so my memory of it is so shakey, but I really enjoyed it and would like to find it again.

It started with a man crash landing on a planet where there is a big order of priests that operate keeping peace in the kind of psychic overworld.  He ends up getting sucked into the rescue of one of them and marries her.  Since she's married she can't be part of the order any more but she was some sort of royalty so they just go to live with her twin sister and her husband.  A good deal of the book is in regards to their relationships and him having culture shock, but at the end they fight some kind of big threat with her psychic powers.

It starts out sci fi but reads like a fantasy book.  Anyone who can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Were the priests/priestesses red-headed? Very loosely, your description could match some of the Darkover stories by Marion Zimmer Bradley or the Witch World novels by Andre Norton (the latter aren't red-headed, IIRC).

Comment: YES!  Thank you!  It was the 4th book, The Forbidden Circle!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103358/looking-for-name-of-a-book-series-spaceship-crashed-civilization-based-on-mag/103426#103426 although they were looking for the series, not a book from it.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260397/sci-fi-book-series-about-a-society-of-human-descendants-on-an-alien-world-who-a (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be [*The Spell Sword*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spell_Sword) by Marion Zimmer Bradley, part of the Darkover series, (details below) or its sequel *The Forbidden Tower*.

> Callista, a Keeper at Arilinn Tower, has been abducted and confined so that she cannot reach even her twin sister Ellemir telepathically. The only person she can reach is a Terran, Andrew Carr, who has no idea what is going on. His search for his "ghost-girl" crash-lands him in the mountains, an experience he barely survives.
>
> Meanwhile Ellemir has sent for her kinsman, Damon Ridenow, a sorcerer trained at Arilinn, to find and rescue Callista. Damon, however is no swordsman; the person for that job would be the girls' father, who has just been crippled by a Cat-men attack. All three men are needed to rescue Callista, and they will need to harness the magic of the spell sword to succeed.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like marion zimmer Bradley's Darkover novel

Comment: Can you add some more details which help the OP figure out it is the book without having to spend time finding the book? Such as a synopsis or a book cover or something?